# Tikhonov regularization in the non-negative least square - NNLS (python:scipy)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-programming, regression, scipy

I am working on a project that I need to add a regularization into the NNLS algorithm. Is there a way to add the Tikhonov regularization into the NNLS implementation of scipy [1]?

[2] talks about it, but does not show any implementation. Sklearn has an implementation, but it is not applied to nnls.

[1] http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html

[2] http://icses2012.pwr.wroc.pl/article/34.pdf

Comment: Could you please comment on the size of your problem? I need to apply NNLS to a problem with 10^5 unknowns, but I do not know if active set methods are feasible for such a large problem.

Comment: What is the dimension of C and d of Brian Borchers's answer?

Comment: If $A$ is of size $m$ by $n$ and $L=I$, then $C$ is of size $m+n$ by $n$ and $d$ is a vector of length $m+n$.  Note that if $A$ is sparse then $C$ will also be sparse.

Answer (score 20):

If what you want is to solve

$\min \| Ax - b \|_{2}^{2} + \lambda^{2} \| x \|_{2}^{2}$

subject to

$x \geq 0$,

then this is easily implemented.  Construct a matrix

$C=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A \\
\lambda I 
\end{array}
\right]$

and a vector

$d=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
b \\
0 
\end{array}
\right]$.

Then use your nonnegative least squares solver on

$\min \| Cx - d \|_{2}^{2}$

subject to

$x \geq 0$.

You can easily extend this to problems of the form

$\min \| Ax-b \|_{2}^{2} + \lambda^{2} \| L (x-x_{0}) \|_{2}^{2}$

by letting

$C=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
A \\
\lambda L 
\end{array}
\right]$

and

$d=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
b \\
\lambda Lx_{0} 
\end{array}
\right]$.

Comment: Nice +1 I would upvote but I'm too lazy to register.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I implemented that, and it runs. I have one more question: How do I choose the value of lambda?

Comment: There are lots of methods for selecting the regularization parameter.  If you know the noise level in $b$, then you can use it as a basis for selecting $\lambda$ (pick the largest lambda that still results in statistically adequate fit to the data.)  A simple heuristic that is commonly used in practice is the L-curve criterion- plot $\| Ax - -b \|$ vs. $\| x \|$, and look for a value of $\lambda$ that gives a "corner" solution that is pareto optimal.  In practice, the choice of $\lambda$ is often simply subjective- what makes the solution look good.

Comment: Excellent answer. I do think there is one small mistake: in case you include a prior you also have to multiply that by $\lambda$, so the last entry in $d$ should be $\lambda L x_0$.

Comment: @tBuLi fixed.  Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 0):

If the fortran code https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/nnls/nnls.f doesn't have a Tikhonov regularization option, then it would probably take some work to add this feature to scipy.

Edit: I looked at the .pdf.  I guess you want to find the smallest $\lambda$ so that $\text{argmin}_x ||Ax-b||^2 + \lambda^2 ||x||^2$ is positive.  I think the $\text{argmin}_x$ for any given $\lambda$ has a more or less closed form solution, and the .pdf mentions bisection search on $\lambda$ until you find the smallest one so that the best $x$ is positive.  This seems pretty straightforward, in the sense that it shouldn't need any weird decompositions or messy fortran code.

Edit 2: I noticed that this question is tagged `convex-optimization`.  If you want to take that approach literally, then you could try cvx (http://cvxr.com/cvx/) or cvxpy (https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy).

Comment: That was my best idea. However, my FORTRAN coding is too weak to do it.

Maybe someone can code it and contribute with the Scipy community.

Comment: I really only want to add any regularization to the NNLS. It was a point that a reviewer on my paper brought up. So I believe I would have to stick with python and NNLS. There are implementations in matlab, but now is too late to change (the paper is almost accepted).